# Updated Image file but not reflecting on Live server in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm new with Laravel and I made web application but when I updated the image file or some css code it will not reflecting on live server.

I tried:
`Route::get('/check',function(){ Artisan::call('cache:clear'); Artisan::call('optimize:clear'); Cache::flush(); });`

but this is not working.
I just want to reflecting updated image file or css file when I update it.

Comment: I think, you need to build assets with npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

"it will not reflecting on live server"

This is the bit that worries me being you've tried the cache clear commands. Laravel will mostly serve up the current assets, there are of course exceptions!
Laravel octane; If you're using this package then `php artisan octane:reload`

Other sources for these sorts of errors to check first would be

1. Browser cache - try renaming the files or adding a query string to their lings.
2. CDN cache - lots of people use cloudflare as a CDN and DNS, make sure development mode is turned on and you've flushed the cache there.

For the most part, just adding a query string and/or changing the name should be enough to prompt a fresh download.